# Rendering the next image when clicked on the next image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousellite

When user clicked on the next image, I want the next image will take the place of current image in the carousal. Is there a way to do this?

My configuration for the jCarouselLite is as follows:

```js
   var carousalConfig = {
            btnNext: '.corousal-nav .right-arrow',
            btnPrev: '.corousal-nav .left-arrow',
            btnGo:[],
            vertical: false,
            visible: 2,
                        start: 0,
            afterEnd: function(a) {
                             a.next().css({opacity:.35});
                             a.prev().css({opacity:1});
                       }


 $('.carousal-coontainer').jCarouselLite(carousalConfig);
```

html for the same

```
<div class="carousal-coontainer">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="image/1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="image/2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="image/3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="carousal_left_arrow"> <span class="left-arrow"> </span></div>
    <div class="carousal_right_arrow"> <span class="right-arrow"></span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: Can you please post a complete example including *compiled* HTML and CSS. The more you provide the easier it is to debug the problem. Also, can you provide a link to jCarouselLite CDN?

Comment: @KalimahApps, I have updated the html and for CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jcarousellite@1.9.2/jcarousellite.min.js

Comment: Ok. I finally was able to get a fiddle working. So in your questions do you mean you want to slide the carousel so the clicked image is moved one step and its adjacent image to move as well?

Comment: @KalimahApps what I want to do is that on click of a next image(in this example blur image) carousal should move the image one step ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jCarouselLite has an event called 'go' where you can specify the slide you want to go to, or (if used without a number) will go to the next slide. In slider options we can add a class to elements that needs to receive click events and then attach a click event to li elements after initialization.

As a side note: jCarouselLite is old and can not work with jQuery 3.0+. There are many free alternatives that provide the same functionality

- **[Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)** - jQuery plugin
- **[Glide.js](https://glidejs.com/)** - dependency-free
- **[Flickty](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)** - jQuery plugin or dependency-free

```js
var carousalConfig = {
  btnNext: ".default .next",
  btnPrev: ".default .prev",
  btnGo: [],
  visible: 2,
  start: 0,
  afterEnd: function(a) {
  // add a class to next element so we can attach click events
    a.next().css({
      opacity: .50
    }).addClass("blurred");
    
    // remove class to remove event attachment
    a.prev().css({
      opacity: 1
    }).removeClass("blurred");
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  let carousel = $('.custom-container');
  carousel.jCarouselLite(carousalConfig);
  // Carousel is initatied so attach click event handler to `.blurred` class
  carousel.on("click", ".blurred", function() {
    carousel.trigger('go');
  })
});
```

```css
#jcl-demo .carousel {
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Needed for rendering without flicker */
  /* position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: -5000px;*/
}


/* Styling for image based carousel content. Only width and height are mandatory */

#jcl-demo .carousel>ul>li>img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 118px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* optional */
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Styling for text based carousel content. Only width and height are mandatory */

#jcl-demo .carousel>ul>li>p {
  width: 130px;
  height: 98px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Styles for PREV and NEXT anchor buttons */

#jcl-demo a.prev,
#jcl-demo a.next,
#jcl-demo a.go {
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: ghostwhite;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  float: left;
}

#jcl-demo a.prev.disabled,
#jcl-demo a.next.disabled,
#jcl-demo a.prev.disabled:hover,
#jcl-demo a.next.disabled:hover {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
  cursor: default;
}

#jcl-demo a.go.highlight {
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #000;
}

#jcl-demo a.prev {
  margin: 10px 0px 0 0;
  text-indent: 7px;
}

#jcl-demo a.next {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

#jcl-demo a.prev:hover,
#jcl-demo a.next:hover,
#jcl-demo a.go:hover {
  background-color: #666666;
}


/* Additional carousel styles for external controls, slider, widget, mid etc. */

#jcl-demo .externalControl button,
#jcl-demo .imageSliderExt button {
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#jcl-demo .externalControl a.next,
#jcl-demo .externalControl a.prev,
#jcl-demo .externalControl a.go,
#jcl-demo .imageSliderExt a.next,
#jcl-demo .imageSliderExt a.prev,
#jcl-demo .imageSliderExt a.go {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 5px 0 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#jcl-demo .widget img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#jcl-demo .mid {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#jcl-demo .vertical {
  margin-left: 170px;
}

#jcl-demo .imageSlider .carousel>ul>li>img,
#jcl-demo .imageSliderExt .carousel>ul>li>img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#jcl-demo .imageSlider .carousel>ul>li>p,
#jcl-demo .imageSliderExt .carousel>ul>li>p {
  width: 380px;
  height: 280px;
}


/* Other common styles */

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jcarousellite@1.9.2/jcarousellite.min.js"></script>
<div id='jcl-demo'>
  <div class="custom-container default">
    <div class="carousel">
      <ul>

        <li><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560577336-4c9f10bdf48f?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=500&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=500" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566535933277-3849dd2833a6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=500&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=500" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561552596-f19273aea403?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=500&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=500" /></li>
        <li><img src="
   https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556560302-312e68d6cbd0?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=500&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=500" /></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```